# When/Why Does Mutual Left Recursion Happen in Antlr?

Tags: recursion, antlr, antlr4

I have an `expression` that is a collection of my other top-level things. In `expression` I have `math` that is `expression (op) expression`. With this I get

**The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [expression, math]**

```
compileUnit : expression EOF;

expression
    : parens                                                            
    | operation                                                         
    | math  
    | variable                                                          
    | number                                                            
    | comparisonGroup                                                   
    ;

math : expression op=( ADD | SUBSTRACT | MULTIPLY | DIVIDE ) expression     #mathExpression;
```

HOWEVER!

This is not a problem-

```
expression
    : parens                                                            
    | operation                                                         
    | expression op=( ADD | SUBSTRACT | MULTIPLY | DIVIDE ) expression  
    | variable                                                          
    | number                                                            
    | comparisonGroup                                                   
    ;
```

And neither is this!-

```
math : op=( ADD | SUBSTRACT | MULTIPLY | DIVIDE ) expression expression     #mathExpression;
```

So why is it that my first code block behaves differently than the other two examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antlr4 can handle direct left recursion, but not indirect left recursion, where a left recursive rule is defined as a rule that "either directly or indirectly invokes itself on the left edge of an alternative" (TDAR; pg 71).

When, as in the first example, the `#mathExpression` alternative is factored out of the `expression` rule and into a separate `math` rule, the left direct recursion becomes indirect, *i.e.*, the rules are 'mutually left-recursive'.

As realized in the second and third examples, a typical solution is to simply combine the indirect left-recursive rules in a single rule.

Comment: Doesn't the first example show direct left recursion- which would also be a problem? I don't have TDAR but I may have to get it.

Comment: Antlr4 can handle direct left-recursion where the recursion "invokes *itself* on the left edge".  The `math` rule is creates an indirect left recursion since it is referencing *another* rule on the left edge.  Highly recommend TDAR.

Comment: Just watched https://youtu.be/q8p1voEiu8Q?t=38m32s. I'm ok with "That's just how it is" for now. Hopefully after reading TDAR I'll have a better understand of *how* everything works and not just *the way* everything works.

Thanks.